# How to properly use findBySomeOtherId not findById in Spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am working on a Spring boot project with spring data jpa(MYSQL)
When I hit this end point `http://localhost:8080/admin/interviews/101`
I get this error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-10-11T13:45:37.111+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Parameter value [101] did not match expected type [com.yash.arci.model.Interviews (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [101] did not match expected type [com.yash.arci.model.Interviews (n/a)]",

    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [101] did not match expected type [com.yash.arci.model.Interviews (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [101] did not match expected type [com.yash.arci.model.Interviews (n/a)]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible
```

This is interviewStatus class

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="interview_status" )
public class InterviewStatus implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -6353284727527331855L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name ="interviewId",insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Interviews interviewId;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name ="statusId",insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Status statusId;
..........
}



@Repository
public interface InterviewStatusRepository extends 
JpaRepository<InterviewStatus, Integer> {

InterviewStatus findByInterviewId(Integer interviewId);
}
```

I want the record on the basis of interviewId. I can already get on the basis of primary key but I want it on the basis of Interview Id, I have interviewId column in interviewStatus table.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also, please write a more descriptive title for your question - a good title makes the question more useful because it makes it easier for people to tell whether the question is relevant to them or not.

Comment: You're getting error messages on the server console. Read them.

Comment: Please try to use this ``InterviewStatus findByInterviewId(Interviews interviewId);``  where interviewId is gotten by running ``Interviews findById(Long id)``

Comment: Thanks @stanlee , the solution is working. I passed Interviews object and set the id keeping everything null.

Comment: you are welcome @Priyam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this `InterviewStatus findByInterviewId(Interviews interviewId);` where interviewId is gotten by running `Interviews findById(Long id)`.

Due to the datatype conflict, it is ok that you pass in as parameter the expected datatype. so it is expecting Interviews not Integer, but you have integer. in this case, you get Interviews using the integer then pass the gotten Interviews as parameter.

Comment: The solution worked beautifully and its returning InterviewStatus Object but what if I want Status object in return. Status is data member of InterviewStatus class.
I tried 
Status findStatusIdByInterviewId(Interviews intervewId ); but it did not work

Comment: Hi @Priyam, you can get Status by using  `@Query(value="select i.statusId from InterviewStatus i where i.interviewId = ?1 ") Status findStatusByInterviewId(Interviews intervewId);`